# Why can't convert an Integer array to an String array using public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original,int newLength,Class<? extends T[]> newType)

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I'm new to Java and am trying to learn the Arrays's class methods. There is a `public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original,int newLength,Class<? extends T[]> newType)` where an array of one type is converted to an array of another type, but I was wondering why converting an Integer array to an String array doesn't work?

```
    Integer[] one = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    String[] two = Arrays.copyOf(one, 10, String[].class);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two));
```

Comment: How would you expect it to convert each `Integer` to a `String`? It would have to "know" to call `toString()` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc tells you the reason :

> **ArrayStoreException** - if an element copied from original is not of a runtime type that can be stored in an array of class newType

An `Integer` can't be stored in a `String[]`.

`copyOf` doesn't convert the elements of the array. It just creates an array of the target type and attempts to copy the elements of the source array to it.